# /etc/sysctl.conf Fedora {17-20}?

Tags: fedora, route, sysctl

Since Fedora 16 or 17 there no longer file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.
How do I setup `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I didn't recognize it and thought it was changed for `sysctl.d/`.

Comment: you can delete your own Question Anytime (if you want!)

Answer (score 2):

I have Fedora 19 installed. It has /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/sysctl.d.

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
```